# Updating and Rendering the Bullet

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

I'm using LibGDX for any of you who it may concern, however I'm trying to create a basic space-shooter game in which the player fly's around using the WASD Keys, and faces the mouse position(I've already done this, yay ;D) Anyway, my problem is I can't figure out how to render the bullet.

Here's my bullet class

```
public class Bullet extends Entity
```

{
    private Vector2 startPosition, targetPosition, position;

```
private float rotation;

private Sprite sprite;

private SpriteBatch batch;

public Bullet(Texture texture, Vector2 startPosition, float rotation, Vector2 targetPosition)
{
    this.startPosition = startPosition;
    this.targetPosition = targetPosition;
    this.position = startPosition;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

public void update()
{

}
```

}

I attempted to implement Runnable and do it that way, however you can't use multiple threads, because it cannot find the instance of OpenGL or whatever.

The goal here is to make the bullet shoot in the direction the player is facing at the time. So, I would create a new bullet as following

```
new Bullet(new Texture("bullet.png"), new Vector2(getX(), getY()), getRotation(), new Vector2(mouseX(), mouseY());
```

My problem is once again, rendering it. I have no idea what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL has some restrictions on how it works in multithreaded environments. Check out http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documentation/parallelOpenGLFAQ.html and pick one of the suggested solutions.

The simple solution here would be to do everything in a single thread.

Somewhere in you code there should be something like

```
while (!shouldExit) {
  Update window stuff.
  Read the state of the inputs.
  Update the state of the scene. {
    for (bullet : bullets) { bullet.move() }
  }
  Render everything once. {
    for (bullet : bullets) { bullet.draw() }
  }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to do this by creating a while(true) loop to process all of the logic and drawing for the bullet, this would stay on the same thread and allow me to access OpenGL, however it instantly froze the application. I attempted adding a Thread.sleep() on the loop, however that didn't do anything either, any ideas?

Comment: Try iterating once over the bullets, and then returning control to the rest of the application, so that it doesn't freeze.

Comment: Not exactly sure how to go about doing that. I need the bullets to be constantly updated. I'm going to be implementing homing bullets, etc, so I will constantly need to do logic checks. 

Perhaps I'm not understanding the information you're providing to me, would you mind displaying this in psuedo?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the created bullet to a variable or a list. Then in your update code, you get it out and call update, and then render it with a sprite batch.
Multithread rendering should not be used in small or medium game. Try to think concurrent, not parallel.